# Matching a URL only if it ends in a certain way, ignoring the order

Tags: java, regex

My content consists of text and links, where some of the links (just some) might end in a pattern `#PARAM1[\w+]#PARAM2[\w+]#PARAM3[\w+]` - the order does not matter and `PARAM2` and PARAM3 are optional. For example, given the url

```
http://www.google.com
```

The pattern should not match, while one of the following should match:

```
http://www.google.com#PARAM1[\w+]#PARAM2[\w+]#PARAM3[\w+]
http://www.google.com#PARAM1[\w+]
http://www.google.com#PARAM1[\w+]#PARAM2[\w+]
http://www.google.com#PARAM3[\w+]#PARAM2[\w+]#PARAM1[\w+]
```

And so forth. For the URL itself I am using the following regex, which is good enough for my needs:

```
\b(http|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?
```

My question is, how can I provide the additional parameters to be included in the match. I have tried to use positive lookahead:

```
\b(http|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?((?=.*#ID\[\w+\])(?=.*#NAME\[\w+\])(?=.*#TAG\[\w+\]))
```

but the matched string only contains the url since the lookahead is not included. There's got to be a simple solution to this! :)

In case it helps, I am using Java for this.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be strict enough for you, and if your data varies much beyond your examples, it might not work, but I took a stab and came up with the following Regex. It is less on the fancy side and more on the brute force side.

```
\b(http|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+(?:(\#PARAM(?:2|3)\[\\w\+])?(\#PARAM1\[\\w\+])(\#PARAM(?:2|3)\[\\w\+])?|(\#PARAM(?:2|3)\[\\w\+]){0,2}(\#PARAM1\[\\w\+])|(\#PARAM1\[\\w\+])(\#PARAM(?:2|3)\[\\w\+]){0,2})$
```

I took the first part of your Regex and then appended a Regex that matches on the 3 alternatives that correspond to the possible positions of required PARM1 in relation to the optional parms:

1. Optional PARM2/3, Required PARM1, Optional PARM2/3
2. Optional PARM2/3, Optional PARM2/3, Required PARM1
3. Required PARM1, Optional PARM2/3, Optional PARM2/3

There's some overlap in the alternatives; perhaps with some more thought it might be possible to simplify them a bit.

As I mentioned, it may not be strict enough for you, as it does not require the optional parms to be unique. This and similar variations will pass:

http://www.google.com#PARAM1[\w+]#PARAM3[\w+]#PARAM3[\w+]

I didn't test exhaustively, of course, so there may be some other bugs, but maybe this will help or give you something to build upon.

Answer (score 0):

Man, I'm a regex guy and I wouldn't try to expand the URL matcher.  Can't you just run your special pattern after running the URL one first?

```
        string verifiedURL = @"http://www.google.com#PARAM3[\w+]#PARAM1[\w+]";
        //match (at least)1, or 2 or 3 occurrences of the PARAM sequence
        var pattern = @"(#PARAM\d\[\\w\+\])(#PARAM\d\[\\w\+\]){0,2}";
        var matches = Regex.Matches(verifiedURL , pattern);
```